# Getting an error of std: bad_alloc while trying to sort an array of objects in c++?

Tags: c++

Codeblocks throwing an error : std:bad_alloc. I am trying to create an array of objects with name and points and trying to sort them via bubblesort.

```
struct Dict{
    string name;
    int points;
};

void bubbleSort(Dict arr[], int n){
    int lastIndex = n-1;
    int swapped = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<=lastIndex && swapped;i++){
        swapped = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<=lastIndex-i;j++){
            int a=arr[j].points;
            int b = arr[j+1].points;
            if(a >= b){
                Dict swapper = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = swapper;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << arr[i].name << " ";
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    Dict arr[n];

    char storeName[20];
    int storePoints;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        Dict a =  Dict();

        cin >> storeName;
        a.name = storeName;

        cin >> storePoints;
        a.points = storePoints;

        arr[i] = a;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "Store name : " << arr[i].name << " Store points" << arr[i].points << endl;
    }

    bubbleSort(arr,n);
    return 0;
```

[throwing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbE9.png)
This is my code for creating object using struct and then storing them into an array of same struct type. But it throws the error.

Comment: `cin >> storeName; a.name = storeName; cin >> storePoints; a.points = storePoints;` why so much unneeded code used? Why not direct read `cin >> a.name; cin >> a.points;`?

Comment: `Dict arr[n];` is not standard C++. It's a language extension that is not supported by most of compilers. `std::vector<Dict>` is a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined behavior caused by attempt to access out of the array bounds.

```
int lastIndex = n-1;  // n is 2, lastIndex is 1
for(int i=0;i<=lastIndex && swapped;i++){ // i is 0 or 1
  for(int j=0;j<=lastIndex-i;j++){  // j is 0 or 1 when i is 0
    int b = arr[j+1].points;  // attempt to access arr[2] when j is 0, UB
    if(a >= b){
      Dict swapper = arr[j];
      arr[j] = arr[j+1];  // attempt to access arr[2] when j is 0, UB
      arr[j+1] = swapper;  // attempt to access arr[2] when j is 0, UB
      swapped = 1;
} } }
```